# What kind of time should I be hoping to achieve inserting 300k records into a SQLite DB?

Tags: sqlite

I've written an app in UWP for Windows Phone 10.

When the app starts, I need to insert 307,750 records into a table. It's currently taking approximately 120 seconds to complete - I've wrapped it in a transaction.

I've been trying to improve performance changing various things but nothing seems to get it any faster than it currently is. Some of the blogs I've read about performance suggest using transactions but I'm already doing this.

does anyone know if this insert time is about the best I'm going to get? Example of the SQL below:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO Point (X, Y, PolygonId) 
VALUES (1,1,1) ,(1,1,2), (1,1,3), ...300,000 more...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Have you checked the CPU and IO levels of your system? If they're close to 100%, your system is doint "everything it can"; and you're provably close to the maixmum limit. One thing to try: do the same thing in *batches* of several sizes (transaction with 1 000 rows at a time, 10 000 at a time, and so on), and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @joanolo thanks for the suggestion, I shaved 15 seconds off moving from batches of 500 to 5000, anything bigger than that didn't seem to have any affect on the total time.

Comment: You've probably reached the maximum your device (and SQLite) can do. Could you keep this table precomputed and stored in a table you don't need to fill every time you start your app?

Comment: Also: does "Point" have any indexes or referential constraints (such as `PolytonID references Polygons(PolygonID)`? If so, try dropping them before inserting, and recreating after. For most DBs, indexing and checking everything in one step is faster than doing it for every insert.

Comment: Inserting 300 000 rows goes *very* fast in [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=cfc72581d19055ed46195a2fa7bc0707), but is obviously not running on a phone.

Comment: Why don't you just ship the final database file?

Comment: @CL. Good suggestion, that's what I did, for some reason it never occurred to me until I created this question! It's always he way!!

Comment: @joanolo I didn't even know about dbfiddle, I'll remember that for future use. I was seeing speeds like that on all blogs I was reading so I thought I had some issue... looks like the issue is the phone!!! I've pre populated the dub with the data as suggested. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

## Things to improve performance of multiple inserts in SQLITE:

### wrap in a transaction

You already done it. This is the first and most important thing.

### Don't use big sentences

You can split the insert statement in serveral

```
INSERT INTO Point (X, Y, PolygonId) 
  VALUES (1,1,1) ,(1,1,2), (1,1,3), ...100 or less... ;
INSERT INTO Point (X, Y, PolygonId) 
  VALUES (2,1,1) ,(2,1,2), (2,1,3), ...100 or less...;
... 10.000 or more statements
```

### Use prepared statements

If the API allows that you can use prepared queries:

```
INSERT INTO Point (X, Y, PolygonId) values ($1, $2, $3);
```

and send the data separately

Comment: SQLite.net seems to ignore everything but the first statement, not sure why but it caused me a major headache until I realised I could do it as I have in he question. Thanks for the suggestions though.